# Select lowest number from column and show other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the lowest number in my RESULT column which I know can be done with MIN but I am not sure how to do this as well as select my other columns. My code displays all the results for all members but I just want it to show the best result (lowest number) along with the other details for that member.

Right now I have multiple entries that look like this:

```
EVENT_ID    EVENT_TYPE  EVENT_NAME  MEMBER_ID   MEMBER_FIRSTNAME    MEMBER_LASTNAME RESULT
event1      track       100M        0001        John                Smith           11.3
```

I just need to select the row with the lowest result and show that one only. Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, R.RESULT
FROM EVENT E, MEMBER M, RANK R
WHERE E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID
AND R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID;
```

SGEDDES - I tried following your last method and couldn't get it to work:

```
SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, R.RESULT
FROM (EVENT E, MEMBER M, RANK R
WHERE E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID
AND R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID;
ORDER BY RESULT)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm use the ROW_NUMBER function to identify which records you want in a cte or nested query and then select where ROW_NUMBER = 1.  I would try to show you but when you say you want the lowest result is that per event, per member, per combination their off or???

Comment: What version of oracle are you running?

Comment: @sgeddes Oracle Application Express 3.2.1.00.12

Comment: @JamesB - you are missing a comma in SELECT, sgeddes had it in his query.

Comment: @mathguy I have added the comma and am now "missing right parenthesis". I have edited the code to add the missing comma.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Apparently you didn't understand <<YOUR QUERY HERE>>. After FROM and the open parenthesis, you did NOT copy your original query. Your original query begins with SELECT, and becomes a subquery in the solution suggested by sgeddes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `row_number` (also please note the `join` syntax -- in general you shouldn't use commas in the `from` clause):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, 
         R.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, R.RESULT,
         row_number() over (order by R.RESULT) rn
    FROM EVENT E JOIN RANK R ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID
         JOIN MEMBER M ON R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

If you need to group the results by a specific field(s), you an use `partition by`.  For example:

```
row_number() over (partition by e.event_id order by result) rn
```

---

And here's another option using `rownum`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (<<YOUR QUERY HERE>> ORDER BY R.Result )
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I tried your last method and couldn't get it to work. I have edited my question to show the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent versions of Oracle, you can use `fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID,
       M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, R.RESULT
FROM EVENT E JOIN
     RANK R
     ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID JOIN
     MEMBER M
     ON R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
ORDER BY R.RESULT
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

If you have a less recent version of Oracle, then one of sgeddes's solutions is fine.

Comment: "SQL command not properly ended".  I like this method is there a way to do it without the last line? WHERE ROWNUM = 1; does not work.

Comment: @JameB . . . If your version of Oracle is older than 12c, then use the solution suggested by sgeddes.